# How to import app file into test file in different directory Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pytest

apologies if I'm going about this wrong, but I am quite new to python and can't quite figure out what the problem is! I have a simple Flask app that I'm trying to write tests using pytest for. The file structure is like this:

```
│── app.py
|── tests
│   ├── tests_app.py
```

I originally had app.py and tests_app.py in the same level and it all worked fine with tests passing, but now I have put tests in their own folder I can no longer import app without error.

I have tried the following in tests_app.py:

```
from app import app #this is what worked fine when app and tests were in the same folder
from ..app import app
from .. import app
```

and the linting error is 'Attempted relative import beyond top-level package' and when I run pytest it says 'ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package'.

Many thanks in advance!

p.s. I am using Python 3.8.5

Comment: [This](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `app` on the [module search path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). A quick fix would be to add the path to `app.py` to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/dir  # where app.py is
```

If `app.py` is on the python path, then `import app` will work (barring any other import problems such as circular imports).

An effective and reproducible way to do this is to *install* your application. You can do this in `develop` mode, which means the code runs from its current directory. This is an understated, important part of developing a Python application, but to do it you will need to write code to [package your application](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html).

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for getting back to me. My app is still very much unfinished as I am writing tests as I go, is packaging something you would do at the end when the app is complete? Also I have tried adding path to dir to PYTHONPATH and im still getting the same error...